# What is the difference between apt-get install php-apc & pecl install apc?

Tags: ubuntu, php, apt

Wanted to setup APC php cache to a fresh 12.04 precise ubuntu box.

Do `apt-get install php-apc`totally replace `apt-get -y install libpcre3-dev; sudo pecl install apc`? If not what are the differences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt-get -y install libpcre3-dev; sudo pecl install apc` will totally replace `apt-get install php-apc`.
Both will install the APC extension for your PHP installation, there are however 2 differences:

1. **Different versions**: apt-get will give you the release as of Ubuntu-12.04's freeze (aka APC v3.1.7), while 'pecl install apc' will give you pecl's latest version (v3.1.9 as of now).
2. **Visibility in the software center**: Installing via pecl circumvents Ubuntu's integrated packaging system, so Ubuntu's apt/dpkg system is not aware of the updated version. In case there's an update Ubuntu may overwrite your side-loaded APC instance with an updated old version.